# How to determine what service was crashed?

Tags: windows, service, monitoring, alarm

Is it possible to determine what service was crashed in RUN PROGRAM option in recovery tab (in services.msc)?

Answer (score 0):

That "Run Program" group has a textbox "Command line parameters" which are passed to the program which will be run.

Simply pass the service name as a parameter. You can then read that from your program.